# Xcode simulator target iOS version names turned to hashes

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.3

I'm on Xcode 6.3. I don't remember doing any special changes but after rebooting my macbook, target iOS version names were like this;

Does anyone know how to quickly fix this? Otherwise my last resort will be deleting all simulators and reinstalling them.

[image: target iOS version names turned to hashes]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate iPhone Simulators Appeared on My Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614197/duplicate-iphone-simulators-appeared-on-my-xcode) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810797/ios-simulator-devices-listed-twice-in-xcode-run-destinations-list

Comment: Also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274517/simulator-name-is-shown-with-id-instead-of-os-name-in-xcode-6-2 // tl;dr Go to Windows > Devices and identify the duplicates in the list and delete them one-at-a-time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are duplicated simulators installed. In Xcode just go to Window -> Devices and delete duplicated devices.