# Xcode duplicated devices bug

Tags: xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator

I opened Xcode and suddenly I found the simulator devices duplicated. I found a similar question [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai9SX.jpg) but that's not my case, I'm using the latest SDK and a clean Xcode installation.
Screenshot in the link bellow. Any ideas?

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai9SX.jpg) [iOS Simulator devices listed twice in Xcode run destinations list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810797/ios-simulator-devices-listed-twice-in-xcode-run-destinations-list)

Answer (score 5):

You can delete the duplicates that you don't want from Xcode's Devices window (Window -> Devices) or from the command line using 'xcrun simctl delete [UDID]'