# Destination toolbar disappeared on XCode 6.4

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Today in the morning I tried to compile my project to run in my device and I found the destination toolbar disappeared and I cannot choose my IOS device or IOS Simulator device as target. (I can do it in the Product/Destination Menu)

[image: XCode6Toolbar]

After some research I found the `>>` at the right on the screen and when I pushed a Scheme option appeared but it is disabled and I can't enable again.

This is what I tried with no success:

- Open an old project to see if the problem was in my project
- Create a new project (with Swift and Objective C but I don't think this make any difference)
- Restart my computer
- Hide and show the toolbar (View menu/Hide Toolbar and the View menu/Show Toolbar)
- I tried all the previous options with the device connected and disconnected

I have installed the IOS Simulator 8.4 (when I run my project it runs in the last selected simulator) and XCode 6.4.

Comment: Even i'm facing the same issue please some one help us out.

Comment: As I added to my question, you can use the Product/Destination Menu as a workaround.  It is not the best way but it works :)

Comment: same problema here and the same workaround

Comment: The same problem! Thanks Apple!! Every time you change normal to debility!

Comment: Same problem on first start up of Xcode 7. I just quit Xcode, started Xcode again.. Appeared as it should have in the beginning :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Looks like Xcode hides that menu when the window is a certain size. I have to make my window quite large before it comes back.

Comment: I tried with the maximum non-retina resolution of my display (1440x900).  Did you try with a higher resolution like 2800x1800?  I didn't try that.

Comment: @CrApHeR yeah exactly, I am on an external monitor and it pops in right around 1520px.

Comment: It's displayed in full screen mode on my 15" mbp retina. Thanks!

Comment: Tool bar will be displayed if you push green button (open large windows). For me works on MacBook Air 13.3 but it's very annoying.

Comment: Thanks god we have a More Space mode in Monitor section. its working fine on that.

Comment: Ha ha ha dude I was in the middle of destroying my mac... After killing processes, rebooting, cleaning hidden files. My hat's off to you.

Comment: I used to surprise how does this happen..... thanks @BrandonWilliams.. this worked for me.

Answer (score 26):

Not a fix as such but you can work around it using the menus: Product > Scheme  and Product > Destination

Comment: This is NOT a fix, but still it works for me :)  I'm using Xcode 6.4 on El Capitan Developer Preview

Comment: the same is happening to me. The menu' was better, but i've wasted enough time searching for a solution

Answer (score 9):

You're probably running into the same issue I am. Like @BrandonWilliams said in his answer, it appears again if the Xcode window is wide enough. The underlying cause, for me at least, seems to be that in this build of Xcode (6.4) running on El Capitan beta 2 (with Xcode 7 beta installed), I am seeing duplicate simulators for iOS 8.4. And since there are two of the same version, the Schemes dropdown shows some sort of long GUID next to each one, causing the Scheme dropdown to be quite large:

[image]

Comment: Solution for removing duplicate simulators is mentioned here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30929023/612794

Answer (score 7):

I came to SO looking for an answer but realized that I had seen this issue before.

So the problem is basically that auto layout sucks (I mean it is not working properly in Xcode 6)  and on El Capitan, the destination toolbar is for some reason hiding instead of collapsing properly. So when your Xcode window is narrow, the destination toolbar disappears.

[image: toolbar is missing]

But, if you expand the window far enough, it shows back up again.

[image: There it is again]

In case you can't tell, in the first screenshot, the window is about 1241 pixels wide and in the second screenshot the window is 1541 pixels wide.

Comment: OMG that works.. how lame is that apple!! come on if steve jobs was alive he would be kicking some ass!

Answer (score 5):

Go to Product then Destination and choose at which simulator or device you want to test your build.[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm running with same problem. You can select device or change scheme using below steps:

1. Select *Product* from menu
2. Select *Scheme* or *Destination*
3. Select required *Scheme option* or *Destination option*

[image: Screenshot for fix]

**Alternative Solution:**

The only solution is to *`use Xcode 7 or above`*. I've *installed Xcode 7.1 and found Scheme/Simulator list available*. Refer screenshot.

It seems that Xcode 6 or below doesn't support OS X El Capitan.

[image: Screenshot for perfect solution]

Answer (score 1):

I am still seeing this problem in Xcode 7.2 on iMac with resolution 1920x1080. Resizing the XCode windows dens't help. I can have the menu bar back if I push the green button and go to full screen mode. But that's pretty annoying. This is how I finally figure out a solution that works for me. I notice that only if I open the project file that I have been working daily that the menu bar is missing. If I create a new project, the menu bar is there. And here is my solution:

1. Remove your project file on disc (or move it to a different folder)
2. Open the **Welcome to Xcode** window by **shift+command+1**
3. Make sure your project is no longer under this list. If it is still there, click on it and Xcode will tell you the project is not found and it will be removed.

[image]

4. Add the project file back and open it and I have my menu bar back (if you have moved it, simply opening it from a different file location may work I guess)

I guess the problem is that some cache value in Xcode about the project file is messed up somehow. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I make my XCode screen little big and now find both options.

Answer (score 0):

On XCode 9.0 beta, this worked for me: select `View -> Show Toolbar` from menu

Answer (score -1):

right click on title bar -> select show toolbar

Answer (score -2):

Fixed it by deleting the following file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist` and restarting Xcode.
The downside is that Xcode preferences dropped to defaults obviously.