# Simulator options won't show in Xcode 6.4

Tags: xcode6.4

I don't get the option to run my app on a certain simulator or anything. I'm trying to upload my app to iTunes Connect but it won't even let me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing your screen resolution, or making the Xcode window wider. Then it will reappear.

If you can't do either of those (do to screen resolution constraints), then use the Product menu and then the Destination sub-menu as a workaround.

And by the way, this looks like a duplicate Question #[31318316](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318316/destination-toolbar-disappeared-on-xcode-6-4)